# While loop freezes up always right before it's finished

Tags: c

I've got this nested while loop, reading lines in from a file and creating an adjacency list. The problem doesn't seem to be with the inner loop, because it gets through that one, but it stops running right before it saves the very last point from the file into the adjacency list. I've tested with several different files (of different sizes), it's always right before the very last point. I can't for the life of me figure out why it would do that, but maybe someone else can help me out?

The lines from the file are stored just fine into the current->next array, it's just the very last of the newPt adjacency list I'm having trouble with. It is, in fact, getting into the while loop the last time, it just can't seem to execute the last couple of lines.

```
while(fscanf(fptr, "%d %d %d", &u, &v, &w) != EOF) { //read from file
    current->next=malloc(sizeof(struct line));
    current=current->next;
    current->u=u;
    current->v=v;
    current->w=w;
    current->useful=0;
    //add point to adjacency list
    currentPt=aList[u];
    while((currentPt->adj)!=NULL) {
        currentPt=currentPt->adj;
    }
    newPt=malloc(sizeof(struct adjacent));
    newPt->x=v;
    newPt->adj=NULL;
    currentPt->adj=newPt;
}
```

These are the structures I'm using, if that helps:

```
    struct line {
        int u;
        int v;
        int w;
        int useful;
        struct line *next;
    };
    struct adjacent {
        int x;
        int onqueue;
        struct adjacent *adj;
    };
    struct adjacent *aList[num+1];
    struct line *current;
    struct adjacent *currentPt;
```

Comment: Since there is no error checking in this code then a number of things could go wrong and make it hard to debug.

1: Ensure that "u" is in the correct range so that "aList[u]" isn't an overflow.

2: "%d" should probably be "%u", at least for "u" since you clearly do not want negative numbers.

3: How is "aList" initialized?
Is it
    adjacent aList[SIZE];    
or
    adjacent *aList[SIZE];
?

Assuming the latter case, how do you initialize these entries? Do you allocate "SIZE" dummy nodes to start with?

Comment: What do you mean by "stops running"? Does it fault? Or does it terminate?

Comment: @joeking All of those are accounted for based on the files that the program is meant to use. There are no negative numbers (they're labeled vertices on a graph), aList is initialized using num, which is the given number of vertices, and all the vertices are given to count in normal order 1, 2, 3, etc without skipping anything.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's where I get lost, it doesn't do either of those. It just sort of freezes, like maybe it's caught in an infinite loop (though I haven't been able to prove that) or something. Does not fault, does not terminate.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your "adjacency list" does not end up with loop, like between lists? I'd explicitly check that (like with debug print).

Comment: @KristinMarks: Add as many printing statements as you have to until you figure out where it gets stuck. Narrow it down as you keep adding statements. That, or learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I've done print statements, that's how I know it gets through the inner loop and freaks out before it can successfully store the final newPt->x. (Or at least, if it does store it, it can't print it immediately after)

Comment: @KristinMarks: What is the last line of code it does execute?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It gets past the newPt->x line, but must not do it properly because when I try printing newPt->x right after it, it won't work.

Comment: Try running your program under `valgrind`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the return value of `fscanf` more closely.  It will return `EOF` if it is at the end of file.  But you need it to return 3, to indicate 3 successful conversions.  It may return `0` if, for example, your file ends with a blank line.

Comment: Ok I've changed it to while (fscanf == 3), but it's still having the same problem. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, sounds like this wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of debugging, you could add lines for printing out the intermediate states:

add

```
printf("%d %d %d %p &p\n", u, v, w, current, currentPt);
```

at the end of the outer while loop.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try following approach..

```
while(!feof(fptr))
{
fscanf(fptr, "%d %d %d", &u, &v, &w);
//Rest of your code in while loop
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, if I do that, it does go through the end of the while loop, but it actually re-reads the data from the last line of the file a second time. Maybe because the files I've been given have a blank line at the end of them? Any thoughts on how to stop it doing that?

Comment: (And then it freezes again, while reading the data from the last line for the second time)

Comment: @KristinMarks: Ignore this code, it is an incorrect method of handling EOF.

Comment: testing for feof before doing I/O is bogus in C, it will only give a proper EOF  indication *after* I/O.